# Drawing text above the divider in an NSSplitView, the top view will occasionally draw over it

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, drawrect, nssplitview

Here's a .swf (pardon, the bad website and swf, that was the only way I could capture what was happening)

http://screencast.com/t/rzJ3b5ihSj

What appears to be happening, is that my divider is occasionally drawn first, and then the top `NSView` in the `NSSplitView` draws over it.  But it seems inconsistent, because sometimes the divider draws on top.

Here is my `-drawDividerInRect` method, overridden from `NSSplitView`

```
-(void) drawDividerInRect:(NSRect)aRect
{
   [[NSColor colorWithRed:10.0/255.0 green:10.0/255.0 blue:10.0/255.0 alpha:0.0] set];
   NSRectFill(aRect);

   id topView = [[self subviews] objectAtIndex:0];
   NSRect topViewFrameRect = [topView frame];

   NSDictionary *attributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:26], NSFontAttributeName,[NSColor whiteColor], NSForegroundColorAttributeName, nil];

   NSAttributedString * currentText=[[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Tool Properties" attributes: attributes];
   NSSize stringSize = [currentText size];

   CGFloat xOffset = ([topView frame].size.width - stringSize.width)/2;
   NSRect textRect = NSMakeRect(topViewFrameRect.origin.x+xOffset, topViewFrameRect.size.height+50, stringSize.width, stringSize.height);

   [currentText drawInRect:textRect];
}
```

How can I make it so my divider & text within it draws on top all the time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So actually the divider, and the text I wanted to draw, were all being done on the `NSSplitView` itself.  The two views on either side of the divider are subviews, and so there's no way to draw in front of them.  What I ended up doing was add some padding at the bottom of the top view so that the divider text is always exposed